# CORS error in JS (XMLRequest)

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, cors

I’m trying to communicate a web page with a RestAPI server. When I try to do an http request the following message appears:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://(MyUrl). Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

`xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); //Some line in my web page code`

`response.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); //Some line in my APIRest code`

I have been doing some research about CORS and I don't understand which headers I have to include to the http request and what headers I have to include in the server to enable it. Should I add something in some .config?

For what I have understood, my petition is a “not-simple” request, as it’s a multipart request with an application/json part that also sends a token into the header. It’s a POST request.

Thanks!

Comment: Has to be set as response headers by server you are making request to. Not set by you in request

Answer (score 0):

It does not help that you set the headers in the client side. The server needs to have that header present in order to allow requests from third parties.

And so this will not work for you as long as the server does not have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set to allow your requests.

You can read more about CORS [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)